# Sending email with included html form

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, html-email

I tried to create and send an email in C# including an html form. GMail seems able to accept it (although i did not yet test the post action), but Outlook (2007 and 2010) is not able to display the form correctly.

This is an example of the code I wrote:

```
using (MailMessage mailmessage = new MailMessage())
{
  mailmessage.From = new MailAddress("noreply@dummy.com");
  mailmessage.To.Add("dummy@dummy.com");
  mailmessage.Subject = "Some subject";
  string html = @"
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id='surveyForm' method='post' action='http://www.someserver.comsomeurl'>
  Survey<br /><br />
  Some question ?<br />
  <input type='radio' name='Q1' id='Q1_1' value='1' /><label for='Q1_1'>Yes</label><br />
  <input type='radio' name='Q1' id='Q1_2' value='2' /><label for='Q1_2'>No</label><br />
  Some other question ?<br />
  <input type='radio' name='Q2' id='Q2_1' value='1' /><label for='Q2_1'>Yes</label>     <br />
  <input type='radio' name='Q2' id='Q2_2' value='2' /><label for='Q2_2'>No</label><br />
  <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>";
  mailmessage.Body = "Some alternate text";
  using (AlternateView alternate = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html))
  {
    mailmessage.AlternateViews.Add(alternate);
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = MyHost;
    smtp.Send(mailmessage)
  }
}
```

In GMail the email contains a form, but in Outlook I get the following:

```
Survey

Some question ?
( )Yes
( )No
Some other question ?
( )Yes
( )No
[Submit]
```

I tried the following variation:

```
mailmessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailmessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
mailmessage.Body = html;
```

But the result was the same.

When I check the source of the mail, it corresponds to the html I generated.

Is what I'm trying to do impossible, or is there a way that is supported by Outlook (and other email readers) ?

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: Yes, that is impossible. Different clients different rules. GMail is just less strict.

Comment: Some things may be impossible, but maybe try removing everything except what's inside the <body></body> tags?

Comment: @Breland: That didn't work either.

Comment: Sorry, forms do not work in emails. As someone who works in marketing, it would sure save us from having to create landing pages all the time if it did.

Comment: @leppie & John: I think you're right. I've given up trying to make it work and just send a mail with a link towards a page with the form. Thanks.

Comment: @Marc did you resolve this issue? I have one similar. If wasn't impossible, may be you can add it as answer.

Comment: No, i didn't, as i said in the comment before yours.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own code, maybe try to use something already did.
Look at http://nuget.org/packages/MvcMailer/ or http://nuget.org/packages/RazorEmail/. This packages should do this work for you.

Comment: I checked the sources of those 2 modules, I don't see how these would help me. They are just wrappers of the SmtpClient. I have no problem sending the mail and I don't see any code that would help me send a form.